# Why does su source code of Android call strcpy() after strdup()? Is this duplicated?

Tags: android

The "su" source code snippet is shown as below:

```
void extract_uidgids() {
    ......
    clobberablegids = strdup(uidgids);
    strcpy(clobberablegids, uidgids);
    ......
}
```

why is strcpy() called after strdup()?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you maybe post more of the code and a link to the full file just in case? Impossible to say what might be going on without more code.

Comment: Does not make sense indeed, only the original developer may know what he was thinking here ...

Comment: The full source is available [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/su/su.c).

Comment: OK, even looking at the full code that doesn't seem to make any sense. Looks like a relatively harmless mistake.